# Seaching for node in ExtJs tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to search for specific node in an ExtJs tree. The current code that I have allows node to be searched only at the first level. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdaXs/3/)

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Javascript",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "ASP.net",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Also ASP.net",
            leaf: false,

            children: [{

                text: '1.1 foo',
                leaf: false,
                children: [{

                    text: "1.1.1 asp.net mvc",
                    expanded: true
                }, {

                    text: "1.1.2 java",
                    expanded: true
                }, {

                    text: "1.1.3 extjs",
                    expanded: true
                }]
            }, {

                text: '1.2 bar',
                leaf: true
            }]

        }, {
            text: "ASP.net future",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Example Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 450,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    multiSelect: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            text: 'Search for ASP.net',
            handler: function () {
                var me = this,
                    panel = me.up('panel'),
                    rn = panel.getRootNode(),
                    regex = new RegExp("ASP.net");

                rn.findChildBy(function (child) {
                    var text = child.data.text;
                    if (regex.test(text) === true) {
                        console.warn("selecting child", child);
                        panel.getSelectionModel().select(child, true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

**What I want:**

1. Ability to search across all the levels in the tree
2. once a node is found, I want to expand it.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for :  http://jsfiddle.net/tdaXs/17/

Thank you Devendra for suggesting Deep Search option.

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Javascript",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "ASP.net",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Also ASP.net",
            leaf: false,
            children: [{
                text: '1.1 foo',
                leaf: false,
                children: [{
                    text: "1.1.1 ASP.net mvc",
                    leaf: true,
                    expanded: true
                }, {
                    text: "1.1.2 java",
                    leaf: true,
                    expanded: true
                }, {
                    text: "1.1.3 extjs",
                    leaf: true,
                    expanded: true
                }]
            }, {

                text: '1.2 bar',
                leaf: true
            }]

        }]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Example Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 450,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    multiSelect: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            text: 'Search for ASP.net',
            handler: function () {
                var me = this,
                    panel = me.up('panel'),
                    rn = panel.getRootNode(),
                    regex = new RegExp("ASP.net");

                //var c = rn.findChild("text", " asp.net", true);

                rn.findChildBy(function (child) {
                    var text = child.data.text;
                    if (regex.test(text) === true) {
                        console.warn("selecting child", child);
                        panel.getSelectionModel().select(child, true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is different from the code you posted above. What code is the correct one?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this :

```
 var c = rn.findChild("text","Also ASP.net",true);
 c.expand();
```

> **true** indicates a deep search.Please have a look at [findChild](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-findChild).

Please check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/tdaXs/8/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply but I am still not able to search node at level 2-3

Comment: It will search for the node at any level.It works.Only the thing is it won't expand.For that you need to check for various conditions such as; 1.a leaf node, 2.it has parent or not.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. if a node is leaf node what needs to be done and if a node is parent node what needs to be done? Please check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tdaXs/14/         I am not able to search at lower levels.